# Will the SseEmitter connection provided by Spring Boot automatically initiate a reconnection after triggering onCompletion?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, backend, server-sent-events

I have created an SSE endpoint for periodically pushing status information to the browser frontend. I'd like to know if, from the frontend's perspective, it needs to manually initiate a reconnection to my /sse/notify endpoint, or if the frontend's EventSource API will automatically initiate reconnections.

Here is my interface implementation.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sse")
@Slf4j
public class SSEController {


    public static Map<Integer,SseEmitter> sseMap=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    /**
     * 获取报警状态的长连接
     * @apiNote 超时时间一小时，结束后SSE会自动重新连接
     */
    @GetMapping("/notify")
    @SaCheckLogin
    public SseEmitter alarm() throws IOException {
        int userId = StpUtil.getLoginIdAsInt();
        SseEmitter sse = sseMap.get(userId);
        if (sse==null){
            sse=new SseEmitter(3600_000L);
            sse.onTimeout(()->{
                sseMap.remove(userId);
            });
            sse.onCompletion(()->{
                log.info("alarm sse complete! userId={}",userId);
            });
            sseMap.put(userId,sse);
        }
        return sse;
    }

    public static void alarmNotify(SSEVo sseVo,SseEmitter sseEmitter){
        try {
            sseEmitter.send(sseVo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("send sse notify error,msg={}",e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Then I set up a scheduled task to push data every 2 seconds.

```java
    @Scheduled(cron = "*/2 * * * * ?")
    public void checkStatus(){
        SSEController.sseMap.forEach((useId,sseEmitter)->{
            List<Integer> accessUnits = sessionService.getAccessById(useId);
            SSEVo sseVo = new SSEVo();
            sseVo.setError(Boolean.FALSE);
            sseVo.setAlarm(Boolean.FALSE);
            handleSSEEmitter(accessUnits,sseEmitter,sseVo);
        });
    }
```

My SSE endpoint encounters an error message after pushing data for some time.

```
2023-10-13 07:36:54.163 ERROR [][] [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:95 - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ResponseBodyEmitter has already completed
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:196)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:127)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:91)
```

Does this mean that I should manually remove the current SseEmitter after the onCompletion() method is triggered, like the following?

```java
 sse.onCompletion(()->{
                sseMap.remove(userId);
                log.info("alarm sse complete! userId={}",userId);
            });
```

And have the frontend initiate a new SSE request, right?

I expect that the frontend can continuously receive data after connecting to the SSE endpoint and automatically reconnect.